# How does it works? Shuffling Array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to understand shuffling arrays in java. I do understand how it works

```
for(int i=myList.length-1; i>0; i--) {
        int j = (int) (Math.random() * i +1);
        double temp = myList[i];
        myList[i]=myList[j];
        myList[j]=temp;
        System.out.print(myList[i]);
```

but I am lil confused about this part

```
int j = (int) (Math.random() * i +1);
```

it can create same numbers for ex:

122512111

So how it works and swaps indexes if it has same numbers.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://youtu.be/4zx5bM2OcvA) visualization.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, no need to worry.

Here I try to explain you `int j = (int) (Math.random() * i +1);` in individual part:

1. `Math.random()` :-> gives you random number in `float` between 0 to 1.
2. `Math.random() * i` :-> multiply with `i(index)` so number don't stay in between range `0 to 1` and range will become `0 to myList.length-2`
3. `(Math.random() * i +1)` :-> increment our random number with 1, so range will become `0 to myList.length-1`
4. `(int) (Math.random() * i +1);` :-> convert our number from `float` to `int`

**all above range is inclusive of the start and end number :)

Comment: Hope you understand right; if you do, please mark your question as answered :)